# Share mocks between different files in karma

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

In my tests I need to do some setup before things can be tested. This setup can be kind of slow.

Right now I'm doing the setup every test:

```
describe("mission", () => {
  it("getAvailableMission", () => {
    generateFiles()
    // do the test
  })
})
```

How can I share the results of generateFiles between multiple files?

It's kinda similar to this question: [How to share a mock between test files using karma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165262/how-to-share-a-mock-between-test-files-using-karma) but I am NOT using angular.

Comment: You can do a `beforeAll` in the tests but that will do the process only once for test file and not for all test files. I am thinking you need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891582/7365461 for `generateFiles` to be called only once for all test files and then the tests can start.

Comment: @AliF50 thanks yeah though that answer is just about how to start the server rather than how to share the result after you get it.